# C++ JsonCpp Change objectValue from an arrayValue

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I want to change the value from `slotList`.

```
slotList[1][1] = "1234";
```

How can I solve this problem?

Here's what I tried:

JSON:

```
{

"slotList" : [

      [ "1452", "1452", "1452", "1452", "1452" ],
      [ "1452", "1452", "1452", "1452", "1452" ],
      [ "1452", "1452", "1452", "1452", "1452" ],
      [ "1452", "1452", "1452", "1452", "1452" ],
      [ "1452", "1452", "1452", "1452", "1452" ]
   ]
}
```

Code:

```c
if (bIsParsed == true)
{
    Json::Value slotList = root["slotList"];

    Json::Value slot = slotList[currentIndex];
    Json::Value value = "111"; // what is wrong? do not change anything! OMG!
    slot[selectIndex].swap(value);
}

Json::StyledWriter writer;
string jsonData = writer.write(root);
```

Comment: Where is `currentIndex` and `selectIndex` set?

Comment: currentIndex is 1 and selectIndex is 1 the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Json::Value& slotList = root["slotList"];

Json::Value& slot = slotList[currentIndex];

slot[selectIndex] = "1111";

std::cout << root.toStyledString() << std::endl;

Answer (score 0):

`currentIndex` needs to be `unsigned`. That is an unfortunate quirk of the API, documented [here](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_value.html). (See `operator[](int)`.)